# Zend decoding html entities in form input element causes empty value

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, encoding, zend-form

I have a form element, called `metaDescription`:

```
        //inside the form
        $description = $this    -> createElement('text', 'metaDescription')
                                -> setLabel('Description:')
                                -> setRequired(false)
                                -> addFilter('StringTrim')
                                -> addValidator('StringLength', array(0, 300))
                                -> addErrorMessage('Invalid description.');               
        $this->addElement($description);
```

Whenever this form loads, I initialize it with a default value pulled from the database:

```
$form->setDefault('metaDescription', $oldPage->getMetaDescription());
```

This works perfectly fine.

However, I now want to `htmlencode` any input description when someone sends the form and `html_entity_decode` the default value that is pulled from the database so that the characters are shown in their original shape again.

I did this like so when handling form input:

```
//handle post
        if ($request->isPost()) {
            if ($form->isValid($request->getPost())) {
                $page = new Application_Model_PagePainter(array(
                    'metaDescription'   => htmlentities($form->getValue('metaDescription'))
                ));
                $pageMapper->save($page);

                ....
```

And I now set the default value like so:

```
$form->setDefault('metaDescription', html_entity_decode($oldPage->getMetaDescription()));
```

At first, this seems to work fine as well. When I send for example `woord1, woord2, me&you` as the description, this is correctly saved as `woord1, woord2, me&amp;you` in the database and correctly displayed again as `woord1, woord2, me&you`. However, when I set a strange character like ó, eg. `wóórd1` this is correctly saved in the database as `w&oacute;&oacute;rd1` but then something strange happens: when the form is displayed again, the default value is empty. When I look at the source, it is indeed empty: `<input type="text" name="metaDescription" id="metaDescription" value="" />`.

This would make me believe that for some reason `html_entity_decode($oldPage->getMetaKeywords())` returns an empty string. However, when I echo it it returns the correct result: `wóórd1`, yet the setDefault has no effect. When I remove the `html_entity_decode` the setDefault works correct again and the value is shown in the form, but without the decoded html entity.

Why is this html entity decode causing the form value to be empty for such strange characters?

**Reply to vstm**

For debugging purposes, I unset encoding like so:

```
$this->view->setEscape(array($this, 'myEscape'));

public function myEscape($inputString)
    {
        return $inputString;
    }
```

Unfortunately, the problem remains the same as explained earlier. Just to clarify, I encode the value before putting it in the database like so:

```
'metaDescription'   => htmlentities($form->getValue('metaDescription'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')
```

And I decode the value after getting it out of the database like so:

```
$form->setDefault('metaDescription', html_entity_decode($oldPage->getMetaDescription(), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'));
```

Very interestingly however, is that it does seem related to the UTF8 encoding, because when I change the encoding to

```
'metaDescription'   => htmlentities($form->getValue('metaDescription'), ENT_COMPAT 'ISO-8859-1')
```

while keeping decoding at UTF8, an input `tést` will result in the input box showing `tÃ©st` rather than an empty value which is the case when setting both methods to UTF8.

Does this help you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I knew it hat something to do with the Zend framework doing its own [escaping](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.scripts.html#zend.view.scripts.escaping) using htmlspecialchars and utf-8 (unless you change that with the view `setEscape`/`setEncoding` methods). And indeed when you do this:

```
$test = "w&oacute;&oacute;rd1";
$test = html_entity_decode($test, ENT_COMPAT, "iso-8859-1");
$test = htmlspecialchars($test, ENT_COMPAT, "utf-8");
```

`$test` is empty at the end.

So you have to call html_entity_decode with "utf-8" or change the views encoding to "iso-8859-1" (or whatever your encoding is). I think supplying "utf-8" is the better option.

### War against the encodings

> Whoever invented character encodings was either an evil genius or a
>   stupid caveman.

To make this work you have also take care of what encoding the browser is using because otherwise you either write garbage in your database, render garbage in your output or both (or nothing, if you hand over the wrong charset to certain PHP-functions). (bear with me)

So first you have to ensure what encoding the browser is using. This can be achieved by:

1. HTTP response headers
2. The Content-Type meta tag (the primary option in ZF)

So check out the content-type meta tag in your HTML-output and what encoding it is suggesting. If there is no content-type meta information or it doesn't include the charset information then you should add one, preferably with utf-8, in your layout (if you're not using layout now is a good time to start with it). This is important otherwise you don't know for sure what encoding your input is or what encoding you have to deliver to the browser. That means something like that is after your opening `<head>`-Tag of every page returned by your application:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

In the following examples we assume you choose utf-8, but you might use whatever is appropriate - if you change the values accordingly (that means s/UTF-8/your encoding/g).

Now, when retrieving data from the browser you know what charset you have to supply for the `htmlentities` call (utf-8):

```
'metaDescription'   => 
    htmlentities($form->getValue('metaDescription'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')
```

So that means that `$form->getValue('metaDescription')` returns an utf-8 encoded string which has to be converted to an HTML-entities string, which is exactly what we want.

So in the database is now the non-threatening string with no umlauts, accents or whatever.

Now we take a look at the editing-part. There you must decode the HTML-entities so the user must not deal with them. The output string has to be encoded with our desired charset (yes, right: utf-8):

```php
$form->setDefault('metaDescription', 
    html_entity_decode($oldPage->getMetaDescription(), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'));
```

So now you have assigned the utf-8 encoded string returned by `html_entity_decode` to `metaDescription` now we only have to get past that `htmlspecialchars` call which is called by default if someone uses `$view->escape()`.

The last step is to ensure that the `Zend_View`'s `encode` is aware of our encoding (this is optional if you are using utf-8 since this is already the default). Either set it for a specific view in the controller with `$this->view->setEncoding('UTF-8')` or for all views in the `bootstrap.php`:

```php
protected function _initView()
{
    $view = new Zend_View();
    $view->setEncoding('UTF-8');
    $viewRenderer =
        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper(
            'ViewRenderer'
        );
    $viewRenderer->setView($view);
    return $view;
}
```

If someone now calls `$view->escape()` it also expects an utf-8 string as input. You should be able to remove the `setEscape` call with the "null" escape.

If you followed all these steps you should now have all special characters with umlauts, accents and graves restored as desired (or I have now disgraced myself).

So every function receives the encoding it expects, otherwise it returns the infamous empty string (pseudo flow-chart):

1. Browser -> sends data in UTF-8
2. `htmlentities($browserData, ,'UTF-8')` -> expects UTF-8 returns ASCII without umlauts or other fancy stuff
3. Database stores ASCII-Text
4. -- Time passes --
5. Then when editing: Load ASCII from database
6. `html_entity_decode($dbData, ,'UTF-8')` -> expects ASCII, returns UTF-8 encoded
7. Via `$view->escape()`: `htmlspecialchars` -> expects UTF-8, returns UTF-8
8. Browser -> expects UTF-8

### tl;dr / recap

- Set a content-type meta-tag with your desired charset
- Ensure that all the encode/decode-functions are aware of the charset you have chosen (that means: be consistent)

Comment: I'm afraid this does not help. I tried changing all encodings to UTF-8, but as soon as I supply something like é or ó the output is empty.

Comment: Where did you change the encodings to UTF-8 exactly? I thought it should suffice if you change the `html_entity_decode` call, the zend-framework is already set to UTF-8 (unless you change it explicitly). If that's really not working you can disable escaping by creating a function which accepts one argument and just returns it and call `$this->view->setEscape('yourfunction')` in your controller to test if the problem really has to do with the escaping.

Comment: I debugged more with your setEscape suggestion, please see my reply in my updated question (at the bottom). Does this tell you anything?

Comment: Thank your for the information. I think the problem is that the browser uses iso-8859-1 as encoding, and by expecting "utf-8" on the server side we just shifted the problem. I have now add some large text which is hopefully not too confusing ;). The main point for you is to explicitly set the charset via meta-tag and also use that charset in the decode/encode-functions. Hope that helps.

Comment: brilliant! I would never have though about the browser worrying with the content type. I set it to UTF-8 and everything works as expected, thanks to your detailed answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Zend_Filter_HtmlEntities() instead of the php functions. It is not doing more than the php functions but it will guarantee a persistent encoding throughout your form.

Comment: Is it possible to make a filter first decode html entities and then encode html entities? This is to prevent double encoding. Eg. &amp; should not turn into &amp;amp;

Comment: Look at the constructor in the filter class and you will see the options you can set and how. The class also has getters/setters to check/change the settings. In that class or with `getDoubleQuote()`  you will see that the default is true so you have to set that to false.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood me. I was not talking about quotes. I'm talking about characters that have already been converted to html entities. Eg. é to &eacute;. If there is &eacute; in the string, it should not be converted to &amp;eacute;. Thus, &eacute; should first be converted back to é so that such dual-conversion will not happen.

Comment: Look at the class. What you think is `getQuoteStyle()`. I agree, though, it is misleading.